# Lower bound on the number of solutions of N-queens problem

Tags: co.combinatorics, puzzle

The [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A000170) lists the number of solutions of N-queens problem
(Number of ways of placing n nonattacking queens on an n X n board). However, no formula is given. It is easy to observe that each number in the sequence is more than double its predecessor.

> Is there any proven asymptotic exponential lower bound on the number of solutions?

Answer (score 2):

Let $Q(N)$ be the number we are interested in. In Corollary 1 on the paper below it is proven that $Q(N) > 4^{N/5}$ for any $N$ divisible by $5$. They also conjecture that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{log Q(n)}{n \log n} > 0$

*Rivin, Igor; Vardi, Ilan; Zimmermann, Paul*, [**The $n$-queens problem**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2974691), Am. Math. Mon. 101, No. 7, 629-639 (1994). [ZBL0825.68479](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0825.68479).

You may also be interested in [arXiv:1705.05225](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.05225) by Zur Luria where Theorem 1.1 gives a lower bound on the toroidal version (hence, also the usual version) of the problem of $n^{\Omega(n)}$ fro $n = 2^{2k}+1$.

Comment: See also Gil Kalai's blogpost on the topic, https://gilkalai.wordpress.com/2018/05/10/zur-luria-on-the-n-queens-problem/